# Wrap ngx-bootstrap/typeahead in an Angular Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap/typeahead to have an autocomplete in my page. This is the code that I'm currently using:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="countryName" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected" (blur)="typeaheadOnBlur()" [typeahead]="countryDataSource" (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)" typeaheadWaitMs="300" typeaheadOptionField="name">
```

Component:

```
asyncSelected: string;

constructor() {
    this.countryDataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
        observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
    }).mergeMap((input: string) => this.getAutoCompleteResults(input));
}

typeaheadOnSelect(event: TypeaheadMatch): void {
    viewModel.nestedProperty.country = event.item.name;
    viewModel.nestedProperty.countryCode = event.item.countryCode;
}

typeaheadOnBlur(): void {
    viewModel.nestedProperty.country = asyncSelected;
}
```

`getAutoCompleteResults()` returns an array of objects (observable) in the following format:

```
[{id: 1, name: "Australia", code: "AU"}, {id: 2, name: "United States", code: "US"}, ...]
```

Now, I think the code in my component does not belong to the component that is just using autocomplete. It also does not make it reusable that much. I don't want to have all these codes in the component and all those `(blur)="typeaheadOnBlur()"`, `typeaheadWaitMs="300"` every time that I want to use my auto complete I'm thinking of creating a directive to use it as follows:

```
<input [myAutoComplete] [ngModel]="viewModel.nestedProperty?.country" (NgModelChange)="viewModel.nestedProperty.country=$event" (select)="mySelectFunction(???)" />
```

As you might have noticed, I couldn't use `viewModel.nestedProperty.country` for my binding with ngx-bootstrap. Looks like that this `$event` has different structure than ngx-bootstrap `$event` in the `typeaheadOnSelect($event)`.

I also don't know how to handle `(select)="mySelectFunction(???)"`. How do you suggest I can make this autocomplete more reusable for my project?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include typeahead component tag in parent component and pass on the values to typeahead component which gets values using `@Input` decorator.I think you would need to know how Angular components work in general , as components by itself is designed in such a way that it can be reused easily.

Typeahead component HTML-

```
<input [id]="id" [(ngModel)]="_model" [typeahead]="workflows" (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)" 
(typeaheadNoResults)="TypeaheadNoResults($event)" (typeaheadOnBlur)="onBlurFunction($event)"
 [typeaheadMinLength]="MinLength" [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="OptionsLimit"
 [typeaheadOptionField]="OptionsField" [optionsListTemplate]="customListTemplate">
```

Typeahead component-

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-input-typeahead',
templateUrl: './input-typeahead.component.html',
})
export class InputTypeaheadComponent{
@Input() selected: any;
@Input() workflows: any;
...
@Input() callback: Function;   
...}
```

Parent component

```
<app-input-typeahead name="requestTypeahead" [id]="workflowId" 
[label]="workflowLabel" [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkflow" [workflows]="requestMatrixList"
[OptionsField]="optionsField"[OptionsLimit]="optionsLimit" [MinLength]="minLength"
[customListTemplate]="customListTemplate" [customItemTemplate]="customItemTemplate"
[placeholder]="placeholder" [callback]="onTypeaheadHandler"></app-input-typeahead>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the directive `TypeaheadDirective` itself and setup the default values that you want in there.
Have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/francarmona/9e7d373e80e9cc9afb9c023923093c01